# why the localhost page isn’t working in lampp (ubuntu)

Tags: 14.04, lamp

I am trying to run my cakephp project in LAMP. My LAMP is already running phpmyadmin and it is also working well for another project. When I search http://localhost/mobishop/ then it works only home page. If I go to my panel with http://localhost/mobishop/mobiadmin it does not work and shows this message: "The localhost page isn’t working."

this is showing in my browser:

The localhost page isn’t working
localhost redirected you too many times.
Try:
Reloading the page
Clearing your cookies
ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Comment: can you add screenshot of the error? or the error which is raised?

Comment: is not it possible insert image again without reputation 10

Comment: The localhost page isn’t working       

localhost redirected you too many times.
Try:     
Reloading the page
Clearing your cookies
ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Comment: Why don't you just share configs and screenshots ? @alamin dawan

Comment: i already try to give screenshots but i got an error it required reputation 10

Answer (score 0):

Browsers, like Google Chrome and Mozilla Firefox, show this error
   as:

```
 Error 310 (net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS): there were too many
   redirects
```

This problem may be caused either at the client end or the server end.
   If there is no redirection loop on the server side, the problem is
   likely to be solved just **by deleting cookies**.

```
Go to Settings → Show advanced settings → Clear browsing data under Privacy options.
```

If this doesn't solve problem, I would
   recommend that first of all you check your `.htaccess` file. Look for any
   cyclic or too many redirection codes. Try to keep your `.htaccess` file in
   a clean state because if this file will become confusing, it can really
   break your website.

Comment: i already cleare my browsers cookies and change .htaccess file does not working .....@Fyodor my project working in windows  but problem in Ubuntu